# Copying a file exatly the same as the original

Tags: sas

I have a .txt file, e.g. the following .txt file(txt_file) has 4 rows, 2nd and 3rd rows have spaces in the front. I am trying to use file statement to make a copy. However, the 2nd and 3rd rows' spaces disappear.

How can I keep the spaces, or an alternative way to keep the spaces, to make sure the copy is the exact same as the original one.

```
abcd efg hijklmn opqrst
     6bho jghvgu
  3hnopkop
1bji njpb 78nhiobhio

data _null_;
 set txt_file;
  file "c:/txt_file_dup" notitles noprint   ;
run;
```

Comment: If you want to preserve leading spaces when writing the text to the file use either $CHAR or $VARYING format in your PUT statement.  If the leading spaces never made it into your variables then make sure to use the $CHAR informat when reading the data from the original text file.

Comment: Do you just want to copy the text file or is there a SAS dataset involved in the process?

Comment: the data actually is table txt_file (i generated the 4 row in this table with the leading spaces).

Comment: To me the word TABLE means a report. Do you mean you have SAS dataset?  If so then describe the dataset. What variables does it have? Are they numeric or character? If character how long are they. Do they have any formats attached to them? The best way to describe a SAS dataset is to post code that can re-create it.

Comment: the data set has only 1 variable, and it is character, actually the values are what i posted above:  abcd efg hijklmn opqrst/        6bho jghvgu       /  3hnopkop /1bji njpb 78nhiobhio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `FCOPY` function.

```
filename source 'original.txt';
filename destin 'original(copy).txt';

%let rc = %sysfunc(FCOPY(source,destin));
```

The filenames can be web addresses as well as local file system.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to copy text is to use the `_INFILE_` automatic variable.

```
data _null_;
   infile 'original_file.txt';
   file 'new_copy.txt' ;
   input;
   put _infile_;
run;
```

To write data from a dataset to a text file use the PUT statement. To preserve leading spaces in the data use $CHAR or $VARYING format in the PUT statement.  So assuming you have dataset named HAVE with one character variable named LINE that is of length 80 you might do something like:

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  file 'want.txt' ;
  put line $char80.;
run;
```

or to not write trailing blanks use $VARYING format instead. To use that you need a variable with the number of bytes to write.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  file 'want.txt' ;
  len=lengthn(line);
  put line $varying80. len;
run;
```

Comment: if the original file is a dataset (txt_file.sas7bdat), what should I modify? thanks!

Comment: If you have a dataset then you need to describe the dataset in your problem statement. What variables does it have. Are they numeric or character?  Do you only want to write some of them to the text file? Which ones?  How to you want to write them to the text file?